# How to get the values of the subscribed data in angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I wrote a injectable service in which i want to return "display" in my data and i done it sucessfully as follows,

```
    export class GetAllList {
    str = localStorage.getItem('social');
    loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
    id =  this.loc._id;
    private _productUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/getprofiledetails/'+this.id;

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getList(): Observable<IDetails[]> { 
        return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
    .map((response: Response) => {    
        return  response.json().data.display; 

        });

    }
}
```

Here i am subscribing to it,

```
 this._profileservice.getList()
        .subscribe(
            details1 => this.details1 = details1);
         console.log("displaystas:"+this.details)
```

The problem is,my console is displaying undefined?so how can i see my display value in my console?Can anyone suggest me help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing wrong variable (`details` instead of `details1`) and you are missing `{}`:

```
this._profileservice.getList()
    .subscribe(
        details1 => {
        this.details1 = details1;
        console.log("displaystas: " + this.details1)
        }
```